# Set a new "next" index for an identity column sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with two columns, id and guid. The Id is the identity column and primary key. This table have been running for a while and are now up at 889 rows. I'd like to change the id to something bigger every now and then, lets say

This should set the new starting index to the table to 1000

```
ALTER TABLE [mydatbase].[dbo].[tblTest]
ALTER COLUMN Id bigint Identity(1000, 1)
```

This however fails.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this would be a solution

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('[mydatbase].[dbo].[tblTest]', RESEED, 1000)
```